# Inserting an array into the database 

Tags: php, mysql

I have am creating a check function that enables me to check that data with the specific `id` and `categoryid` is already present in the database:

```
$fields['Occupation'] = array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "7" }
```

**Line in question:**

```
$occCheck = Jojo::selectQuery("SELECT * FROM {refocus_candidate_category} WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation']));
```

**Why am I getting this Error and how do I resolve:**

```
Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
```

**Full Check Function**:

```
    if($occCheck != FALSE)
    {
        Jojo::updateQuery("UPDATE {refocus_candidate_category} SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation']));
    }else{
        Jojo::insertQuery("INSERT INTO {refocus_candidate_category} SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?", array($emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation']));
    }
```

Comment: @Shades88 Why am I getting the error & how do I fix

Comment: check my answer, hope that might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do in your queries, as you are writing these strange values `SET canid=?`.

But the problem you are facing is, that you are concatinating entire array in your SQL query string. try to `echo` an array then you will see it getting printed as `Array`. That's the source of your problem query gets expanded like `someField=Array`. Now that `Array` is not even in single quotes, so mysql is assuming it to be a column. Thus your error.

Remove that `array($emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation'])`. And just set `$emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation'][0]`. your `field['Occupation']` is and entire array so choose some as per your need.

Comment: Hey,  I am now getting Input Array does not match ?: SELECT * FROM `refocus_candidate_category` WHERE canid='11' AND categoryid=
SELECT * FROM `refocus_candidate_category` WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=? why?  Also it did insert but only 1 value

Comment: it looks like that function internally does something to array arguments passed to it. then try `array($emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation'][0])`

Comment: I now get Input Array does not match ?: UPDATE `refocus_candidate_category` SET canid='11', categoryid='1' WHERE canid=
UPDATE `refocus_candidate_category` SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=? Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 1 )

Comment: try `array($emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation'][0], $emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation'][0])`.... just a random guess. The reason for this guess is that, there are 4 placeholders in your sql query string. your function may be trying to replace them with input array elements. In input array we specified only 2, lets try putting 4

Comment: INSERT INTO `refocus_candidate_category` SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=? Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 8 [2] => 11 [3] => 8 ) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE canid='11' AND categoryid='8'' at line 1

Comment: dive inside that damn function named `insertQuery` and try to print the actual string form of sql query being formed. I think that input array mismatch error has gone away, some SQL specific error now remains.

Comment: How can I tell you? That function there is a clearly a custom function that does some replacement to the string and it's `?` using input array. You will have to find it out yourself by looking into that function's code. Locate class file for Jojo class or whatever's the name then locate `insertQuery` function in it and find out how it works. This class and function looks like reaaaallly weird functionality to me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16935/discussion-between-jess-mckenzie-and-shades88)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16967/discussion-between-jess-mckenzie-and-shades88)

Comment: nope I wasn't. But I see this has solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks `$fields['Occupation']` is an array and it's going to be replaced by `categoryid=>?< category ID`. What about doing it step-by-step for each category make a question to the database?

OR

```
$occCheck = Jojo::selectQuery("SELECT * FROM {refocus_candidate_category}
                               WHERE canid=".$emailCheck['id']."
                               AND categoryid in
                                 (".implode(",",$fields['Occupation']).")");
```

if  `$emailCheck['id']` is not an array

Comment: I get Input Array does not match ?: UPDATE `refocus_candidate_category` SET canid='11', categoryid=Array WHERE canid=
UPDATE `refocus_candidate_category` SET canid=?, categoryid=? WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=? Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 ) ) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1array(5)

Comment: Jess: SO as I wrote, use where operator IN and implode array to set of Ids

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you're passing an `Array` to the `...Query(` functions rather than separate arguments? PHP is passing the one parameter through to the database - which interprets it as a string - so your query is actually searching for the word "Array" instead.

Try this instead:

```
$occCheck = Jojo::selectQuery("SELECT * FROM {refocus_candidate_category}".
                              " WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?",
                              $emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation']);
```

Comment: I need to check if there are any occupation options that match my id - If there is I would like to insert new options else insert the lot.

Comment: I get Input Array does not match ?: SELECT * FROM `refocus_candidate_category` WHERE canid='11' AND categoryid=
SELECT * FROM `refocus_candidate_category` WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make up your mind what Occupation you want to query for:

```
$occCheck = Jojo::selectQuery("
   SELECT * FROM {refocus_candidate_category} WHERE canid=? AND categoryid=?",
   array($emailCheck['id'], $fields['Occupation'][1]));
```

In this case i used occupation with index 1, and that will result in occupation 6 selected.

Comment: I need to check if they all are present